# How "const int *const & variable" is interpreted in c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

When one aliases two variables as

```
int a;
const int &b = a;
```

the two variables are effectively the same thing, so that any change applied to the variable `a` is also applied to the variable `b`. However, when the same trick is done with pointers, it does not seem to work in the same way, as is demonstrated by the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {

    int *a = (int*) 0x1;
    const int *const &b = a;// Now b should be an alias to a.
    a = (int*) 0x2;// This should change b to 0x2.
    std::cout << b << "\n";// Outputs 0x1 instead of the expected value of 0x2.

    return 0;
}
```

Now the variable `a` does not seem to be an alias of the variable `b` after all, but why?

Comment: https://cdecl.org/

Comment: In your first example you added only **one** `const` in the reference type. In your second example you suddenly added **two** `const`s. Why two? This is what makes your second example very different from the first. If you wanted similarity, you should have simply done `int *const &b = a;`. That would've made your second example behave similarly to your first.

Comment: Imho the compiler should issue a warning about situations like this.

Comment: The reason I used two `const` modifiers is because I wanted to prevent modification of the pointee data through `b`.

Comment: Note that `a` is declared to point to the memory address `0x1`, which is UB to start with. You cannot just write somewhere in memory, and especially not in `0x1`. You should have point `a` to some proper address.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`const int *const &` is a reference to `const` pointer to `const int`. (Try to read it from right to left.) Note that the pointer's type is `const int *`, but not `int *` (i.e. the type of `a`). References can't be bound with different type directly. For `const int *const &b = a;` a temporary<sup>*</sup> (with type `const int *`, copied from `a`) will be constructed and then bound to the reference; the temporary has nothing to do with `a`, so any modification on `b` won't effect `a`.

Note the difference. In the 1st sample, `const` is quafied on `int`; in the 2nd sample, `const` is qualified on not only the pointer itself, but also the pointee, which makes two pointers different types (`int *` vs. `const int *`). If you want to qualify `const` on it (which seems unnecessary for your experiment) you should only qualify it on the pointer itself, i.e. `int * const &`.

---

<sup>*The [lifetime of the temporary](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime#Temporary_object_lifetime) is extended to the lifetime of reference `b`.</sup>

Comment: Removing the first `const` modifier does cause the variables `a` and `b` to become aliased, however, I don't see why it should be not possible to declare `b` in such a way that prevents modification of the data (`*b = `), while aliasing `b` with `a`.

Comment: @marde I might not get what you mean correctly; you can declare `b` in such a way and it does prevent the modification on the pointee like `*b = ...`; even `b` isn't an alias of `a`, but `b` and `a` still point to the same pointee; so declaring `b` as pointer to `const` matches your intent.

Comment: Declaring b as a pointer to const (`const  int *b = a`) would work in a desired way, except if i change the pointer `a` later, for example with (`a = malloc(SIZE)`). Then the pointer `b` will still point to the old location, which is not wanted.

Comment: @marde AFAIK, you can't achieve that, i.e. when `a = ...` `b` is also effected and `*b = ...` is banned.

Comment: @marde Or you can change `a` to pointer to `const` too, i.e. `const int *a`; but it will also make `*a = ...` impossible.

Answer (score 5):

`const int * const & b` means reference to const pointer to const int. What you want is `int * const & b`

Use this handy tool to decipher complex declarations. https://cdecl.org/